# how to set cookie before sending response node js (Sails)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I am having a problem if the cookie will be set before the the response is being sent.
like i want to set cookie for logged in user and then i want to send the response OK.

```
User.find({user:req.body.username,password:req.body.password})
  .exec(function(err,row){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.negotiate();
  }
  else if(row.length){
    res.cookie('user',{user:row[0].user,role:row[0].role},{
      signed:true,
      httpOnly:true,
      maxAge:1000*60*60*24*5
    });
    res.end('You are logged in successfully');
  }
  else{
    console.log('nothing executed');
    res.end('Not such a user');
  }
});
```

is it sure that the `res.cookie()` will be executed before `res.end()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "set" a cookie by sending a `Set-Cookie` header to the browser. Therefore, strictly speaking, it is not possible to set a cookie *before* sending a response. Calling `res.cookie()` just *prepares* the respective header but does not actually send it.

I see you use cookies to store user data, so in this case you might be better off using a session module like https://github.com/expressjs/session -- it will let you read or write data at any time and handle the low-level cookie business for you.

Comment: res.end() will be sending response thats why i want to be sure whenever the res.end() is sending the response, res.cookie() has done it's work!!!!

Comment: Then I am not sure what your question is. `res.cookie()` is a synchronous call. If it does not throw an exception, you can be pretty sure that it worked. If you're extra paranoid, you can double-check by using `res.get('Set-Cookie')` to retrieve the header and verify if the cookie has been "baked". See an example here: https://github.com/plus3network/dongle/blob/master/index.js